# Enterprise Deployment w/New Device

Tags: ipad, deployment, ios-provisioning

Attempting to deploy an Enterprise application wirelessly, with partial success. I do have the Enterprise Developers Kit, I've created the provisioning profile, added the devices ID's, uploaded the mobile provisioning profile, the ipa, and the P-list.

When I install the app through xCode directly onto the iPad, then attempt to download it wirelessly, it works fine. When I attempt to use it on a device that hasn't had that direct install, it downloads about 66%-75% of the way, right when the title shows up on the app, then says "Unable to Download Application".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you're on here, you should check to see if your iPad or iPhone is up to date with whatever version you archived it with on xCode. I updated the iPad to 5.1.1 and it installed just fine. My bad.

Comment: Actually no. You had your settings incorrect with the certificate. You register the app name on the portal, download the ditribution certificate and when building select that certificate. Also, the plist values have to be exact for the url.

Comment: Yeah, didn't actually change any of those things to get it to work.